# JPA NamedQuery not in Glassfish4 (but works in Glassfish3)

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I am migrating an application using EJBs with JPA (EclipseLink) from Glassfish3 to Glassfish4. Most of the is working on the new server, but for some reason this named query, where an object is instantiated within the JPQL statement, is not working:

```
@NamedQuery(
    name = "countByUserType", 
    query = "SELECT new org.util.CountBean(ev.user.type, count(ev.user.id)) 
             FROM Event ev WHERE ev.idTs = :idTs GROUP BY ev.user.type"
)
```

My class CountBean is a simple POJO class

```
public class CountBean{
    String label;
    Long count;
    public CountBean(String label, Long count) {
        this.label = label;
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

The error message I get is below:

```
 Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
 Exception Description: Query failed to prepare, unexpected error occurred: [java.lang.NullPointerException].
 Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
 Query: ReportQuery(name="countByUserType" referenceClass=Event jpql="SELECT new org.util.CountBean(ev.user.type, count(ev.user.idU), 0l) FROM Event ev WHERE ev.idTs = :idTs GROUP BY ev.user.type")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.prepareFailed(QueryException.java:1584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkPrepare(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDatabaseQueryInternal(QueryImpl.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1107)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:522)
    at org.un.sers.repository.EventFacade.countRoomsBooked(EventFacade.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 35 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ConstructorReportItem.initialize(ConstructorReportItem.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.prepare(ReportQuery.java:1058)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:661)
    ... 69 more
```

I would appreciate to get some insights from someone who experienced a similar issue or if there is something that seems off in the code I posted. Again, this works when I deploy the application on Glassfish 3, but not on Glassfish 4 and the database it connects to is Oracle 11g.

Comment: Can you show the stack for the error?

Comment: which version of eclipse link you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is bug** in the old versions of eclipselink, check this :

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=446861
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=444561

---

**Solution**

The better way to solve it is to upgrade to the latest versions 2.7.1 [Latest Release](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/)

---

**Beside I would like to use [Payara Server](https://www.payara.fish/) instead of GlassFish 4 Server**, there are many bugs was fixed I have a good experience with this server, it is more performance and more quick than GlassFish now.